# Select all textboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which displayed a person's info in a table(fields:name, surname, address, etc.) and one of the inputs is a checkbox. The code is as follows:

```
  $("#table").append('<tr class="trow'+j+'">'+
                      '<td class="ids" id="z'+i+'">'+totrecs+'</td>'+
              '<td>'+member[i].jdate+'</td>'+
              '<td class="users" 

              '<td id="contact'+i+'">'+member[i].fname+' '+member[i].lname+'</td>'+
              '<td id="myaddress'+i+'">'+member[i].address1+' '+member[i].town+'</td>'+

              '<td><input type="checkbox" name="whome" id="showMe'+i+'"'+
                                             'class="boxes" onclick="getMe('+i+')" /></td></tr>');  
      totrecs++;
      j++;
     }
```

What I am tryin to do is program a function that when clicking a certain button all of the checkboxes will be selected/checked.

I would appreciate any help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Check/Uncheck All" />

$('#btnId').on('click', function() {

    var check = false;

    if( !$(this).hasClass('checked')){
        bool = true;
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('checked');

    $('#table input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', check)
});
```

Comment: in btnId, am I suppose to add the id of the button or the checkbox?

Comment: that is the id of the button

Comment: thanks for the code but it doesnt seem to work, i have gave the button id="btn", changed btnId to btn in the js, and copied the code to my js file, is that right ?  or should i change the table input? thank you

Comment: if id="btn"  the selector will be $('#btn')

Comment: can you reproduce that in a Fiddle

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful: [JQquery Select All Checkboxes tutorial](http://jetlogs.org/jquery/jquery_select_all.html)

Answer (score 0):

To check all checkboxes in `#table` using jQuery:

```
$('#table :checkbox').attr('checked', '');
```

Note that this will not trigger any click events you set for the checkboxes. You should use the `change` event instead of `click` to make it happen as expected.